# PHP - Extraction two data from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string: `Glass with digitizer - black (iPhone 6)`

Now, I want to extract two substrings: `Glass with digitizer - black` and `iPhone 6`.

I can make it this with:

```
$string = 'Glass with digitizer - black (iPhone 6)';
$string = explode(' (', $string);
$first = $string[0];
$second = substr($string[1], 0, -1);
```

However, I want to achieve the same with a regex because the format is constant: `first` `(second)`.

Comment: so what you have done already? :) Tried anything with regex?

Comment: since this is not a regex answer, I will put it here for my try :), `$second = strrchr($string, "("); $first = str_replace(" $second", "", $string);`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(.+?)\s*\(([^)]+)\)$/
```

Should work well enough

https://regex101.com/r/wD9iU6/2